# how to handle PHP function() return value in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, return-value

I'm Trying to insert the HTML Form data using PHP with the help of Ajax,
I write the code for that is as follow
html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Ajax Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
function exec(){
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var xtr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xtr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xtr.readyState==4 && xtr.status==4){
            document.getElementById("p_res").innerHTML=xtr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xtr.open("GET","insert.php?name="+name+"&uname="+uname,true);
    xtr.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Name : <input type="name" id="name"><br>
    Username : <input type="uname" id="uname"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="exec()">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="p_res"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the respective php page is it.. it return some value but the Ajax code does not print then at specified location which has been assigned for that code.. what should I do to resolve this fault..

```
<?php
class insert
{
    /**
     * insert constructor.
     * @param $name
     * @param $uname
     */
    function __construct($name, $uname)
    {
        $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=password");
        if (!$conn) {
            return "Error, Could not connect!";
        }
        $query = "INSERT into test(uname,name) VALUES ('$uname','$name')";
        $res = pg_query($conn, $query) or die("Can not exec Query...");
        return (<<<ret
Data Inserted Successfully...
ret
        );
    }
}

/** @var TYPE_NAME $obj_test */
$obj_test=new insert($_GET['name'],$_GET['uname']);
?>
```

Please Support me guys because I'm new for ajax, I do not have any great idea about the ajax...
                    Thanks guys....

Comment: sorry guys I want to put some info here.. Data in the database insert successfully but does not return any value... I mean noting is display on the html page regaded to the respective database success message..

Comment: class constructor functions don't return a value, they return the instance of the class object.

Comment: Simple suggestion, take it for what you will ... use of `onclick` attribute is unnecessary. Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to return a value from the constructor, use another function for that purpose perhaps as below.

```
class insert{
    /**
     * insert constructor.
     * @param $name
     * @param $uname
     */

    private $res;

    function __construct($name, $uname)
    {
        $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=password");
        if (!$conn) {
            return "Error, Could not connect!";
        }
        $query = "INSERT into test(uname,name) VALUES ('$uname','$name')";
        $this->res = pg_query($conn, $query) or die("Can not exec Query...");
    }


    public function showsuccess(){
        echo $this->res ? 'Data Inserted Successfully...' : 'Error inserting data';
    }
}

$obj_test=new insert($_GET['name'],$_GET['uname']);
$obj_test->showsuccess();
$obj_test=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code. First of all, the constructor method doesn't return anything. So instead of `return` use `echo`, like this:

```
<?php
    class insert
    {
        function __construct($name, $uname)
        {
            $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=password");
            if (!$conn) {
                echo "Error, Could not connect!";
            }
            $query = "INSERT into test(uname,name) VALUES ('$uname','$name')";
            $res = pg_query($conn, $query) or die("Can not exec Query...");
            if($res){
                echo "Data Inserted Successfully";
            }else{
                echo "Data could not be inserted";
            }
        }
    }

    $obj_test=new insert($_GET['name'],$_GET['uname']);
?>
```

And second, look at your `onreadystatechange` event:

```
xtr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                                ^ you are not catching the response text
    if(xtr.readyState==4 && xtr.status==4){
                                        ^ status should be 200
        document.getElementById("p_res").innerHTML=xtr.responseText;
    }
};
```

So your `exec()` function should be like this:

```
function exec(){
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var xtr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xtr.onreadystatechange=function(responseText){
        if(xtr.readyState==4 && xtr.status==200){
            document.getElementById("p_res").innerHTML=xtr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xtr.open("GET","insert.php?name="+name+"&uname="+uname,true);
    xtr.send(null);
}
```